# Amazon Load Balancer sticky sessions with ajp:8009

Tags: amazon-elb, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

We configured ELB with sticky sessions for the JSESSIONID cookie for two tomcats (tomcat1 and tomcat2)(Flow is - Apache Http Server - ELB - tomcats)

AJP protocol with port 8009 has been configured on tomcat side as from AWS ELB there is no AJP option, we have configured with tcp:8009

So the Apache httpd.conf entry is,  (xxx.amazonaws.com is ELB name)

BalancerMember ajp://xxx.amazonaws.com:8009

Somehow the sticky session is not working, the http request is sent to both tomcat servers.  Is it because of the protocol on ELB side (tcp:8009)?  We are not sure what is missing here, Need help!!

Answer (score 0):

Once you change it to TCP you lose sticky sessions. It is an ELB limitation.  You might be able to get away with switching the protocol to HTTP but with a different port other than 80.

Unless I am mistaken, you might have to setup an HA Proxy or something else instead of the ELB. Something that can do both TCP with sticky.

It is well know that websockets+sticky doesn't work on amazon.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=627367

Comment: We have added Apache infront of Tomcat that is ELB->(HTTPS)Apache->(AJP)Tomcat and that worked. Thanks for your suggestion.